# Simple xamarin android application works in VS but fails on phone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, visual-studio-2017

I have *Samsung A8* phone. *Android* version - 7.1.1

Trying to create simple application using *Xamarin* on *Visual Studio 2017*. In the *project properties -> Application* I've set "*Use Latest Paltform (Android 7.1 (Nougat))*".

This is my source code.

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textLizaMath" />
    <Button
        android:text="Click"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnLizaMath" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**BtnClick.cs:**

```
namespace Core
{
    public static class BtnClick
    {
        public static string GenerateText(string text)
        {
            if (text.Equals("text1")) return "text2";
            return "text1";
        }

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Mobile
{
    [Activity(Label = "LizaN", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            var btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLizaMath);
            var lizaText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textLizaMath);
            btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var tmpText = Core.BtnClick.GenerateText(lizaText.Text);

                lizaText.Text = tmpText;
            };

        }
    }
}
```

When I launch it in *VS* it works as expected. Then I go to *bin/debug* folder and copy both *Mobile.Mobile.apk* and *Mobile.Mobile-Signed.apk* to my phone. *Mobile.Mobile.apk* is not installing at all as saying that it is corrupted. I am able to install *Mobile.Mobile-Signed.apk*, but when I try to run it crashes without any meaningful error message.

What can I do?

UPDATE:

I've tried to do "archive" then it failed with the error message: "shared mono runtime is enabled", I went to *project properties* -> *Android options* and disabled "*Use Shared Runtime*". After that I was able to archive it. The size of the application increased 10x. I've copied all the files (not only .apk) but when I tried to install it said that the "*package is corrupted*" (I do not know exact English error message text but it is something like that)

Comment: If you [create a release version of APK](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/release-prep/#archive) and install it, will that crash too?

Comment: I think it would be reasonable to first read the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/release-prep/) of publishing an APK which includes creating and signing the APK with a certificate. For the size of APK, there are a couple of [options](https://montemagno.com/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down/) you can apply.

Comment: Also make sure that your device Android's version is not lower than the minimum SDK version set in properties.

Comment: Do I need to go through that release process even if I am not going to publish it to the market? Btw, I do not care about the application size right now at all. I just want to make it working somehow.

Comment: Yeah you need to publish the APK in "ad hoc" way in order to test your app on devices (not market).

Comment: I've set the CPU version and was able to run it on device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore your nuget packages. Update xamarin.forms nuget also.

Comment: I've set the CPU version and was able to run it on device.